# How can I get clearInterval to stop my timer?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have 2 timers I want to run seperately. 'timer'is linked to the first function 'timePassed' and should count up until the vital stats of my creature go down to 0 then it should stop. It does. However, my second timer, 'timer2' is linked to the second function 'restart'. It isn't stopping when the stats reach 0, which is want I want. Just like the first.

I suspect it might have to do with my running of 'timePassed'(function 1) within function 2 'restart'. I feel the timer runs too fast for 1 second intervals so that's another clue.  But I'm not sure as I'm new to all this. Basically, how can I stop 'timer2' as soon as the stats reach 0?

```
//first function that works fine

function timePassed(){
    message();
    screen();
    i++;
    answer();
    decrease();
    changeStar();
    changeDonut();
    changeHeart();
    if (health === 0 || happiness === 0 || hunger === 0){      
      dodo();
     clearInterval(timer);
          }
  }var timer= setInterval(timePassed, 1000);

//second function whose timer isn't working correctly

 function restart() {
   i=0;
   message();
   health = 4;
   happiness = 4;
   hunger = 4;
   screen();
   timePassed();
   if (health === 0 || happiness === 0 || hunger === 0){      
      dodo();
       clearInterval(timer2);    
      }
    } var timer2 = setInterval(timePassed, 1000);
```

I've tried assigning var timer2 to both timePassed() (as shown) and restart(). If I use restart(), my counter bounces up and down never decreasing enough to trigger the clearInterval.

If I remove the 'if' statement from restart(), and/or timer2, restart() just sits and doesn't count down.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully give you more insight of what else may be wrong with your code. Let me know if I can assist you further.

Answer (score 2):

After some thought here are the issues you're facing:

- `restart()` will never enter its `if` block, because you're reassigning variables it checks beforehand, that's why second interval will never get cleared
- you're running two exact same timers, so every second `timePassed()` is called twice
- you're calling `timePassed()` again in `restart()` which not necessarily is causing problems, but for sure it increases value of `i` right after you set it up to 0 (the bouncing counter issue)

So, answering your question - to stop `timer2` as soon as stats reach 0, you can simply move `clearInterval(timer2)` to the `if` block inside `timePassed()` and i.e call `timePassed()` before you reset stats and counter, or just clear both intervals in `restart()` without calling `timePassed()`. It all means though that you'll be clearing both intervals which may not be what you want.

However looking at the code you provided, running two exact same timers doesn't make much sense - you could just run one timer with half of the delay and achieve pretty much the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do use restart() as you click on the restart button that runs it.  In the first function, decrease() changes those reinitialised variables downwards so it's definitely hitting 0 (or at least function 1 is) as dodo() runs. I think I'm beginning to see what you mean. I'll try and split timer() into 2 to try and avoid that second block from not running...I'll be back in a bit!

Comment: @LornaRoberts It's really hard to guess what exactly your code is doing and what general outcome you'd like to achieve _(apart from working timer of course)_. If you could share a bit more, maybe I could help more.

Comment: Thanks @Coldark. Much appreciated. Cut my code down to try and make it relevant.  Basically, I am trying to make a virtual pet. Simple timers etc. Every second it runs, a random number is thrown up which dictates which of 3 life stats (hunger, health, happiness) decreases by one. The player can add these back onlick of the icons e.g. pill, sandwich, toybox. All I want is the timer to tell the player, how long the game lasted before one of the life stats decreases to zero.

Comment: Presently,  function1 continues to keep running (which it wasn't before). Function 2 is also running on. I agree that there should only really be one timer. But I'm not sure how to achieve that as if I don't have a timer running attached to function2, it doesn't run at all.

Comment: @LornaRoberts What does this code is supposed to do exactly (what's the idea behind it)? I can't help you really unless you clarify that.

Comment: @Coldark- sorry. Thought I'd explained. Function 2 does basically the same as function1, except that the life stats are reset to 4 before it begins as that happens automatically for function 1. All I want is a singular timer that runs either on screen load (function 1) or from clicking restart (function 2) that gives me a variable (i) that I then use via innerhtml to show on screen once a life stat has gone to 0. e.g. you have lived 2 days. I'm not even certain my 'if' statement is executing at all in function 1 or 2 now. Is that more what you mean about the idea behind it?

Comment: @LornaRoberts Please take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jywd6acp/1/)

Comment: @Coldark- I can't believe the amount of work you did! Thank you so much. The only problem is that I'm still trying to achieve the above with a single button. I'd prefer to just have one button for the sake of simplicity. Is it too difficult to achieve? Thanks to your fiddle, I was able to stop my counter using timer = null. But the restart() just parrots the previous refreshed timePassed() i count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208814/discussion-between-coldark-and-lorna-roberts).